# webscrape returning empty string after visiting each href link

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the below code giving me the correct href links to the product detail pages, however, my scrape result is showing an empty list.I am wanting to fetch the product description under the "add-to-cart" button. What am I missing here?

Output:

`https://www.nike.com/t/nikecourt-air-zoom-vapor-x-mens-hard-court-tennis-shoe-6J0fk8/AA8030-103
[]
https://www.nike.com/t/nikecourt-zoom-cage-3-mens-hard-court-tennis-shoe-mbXWvX
[]`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from random import randint
from time import sleep

final = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Selenium/bin/chromedriver')
    ###########THIS IS THE URL 
    driver.get('https://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-tennis-shoes/7puZ8r0Zoi3')
    products = [element for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='grid-item fullSize']")))]
    driver.execute_script('el = document.elementFromPoint(47, 457); el.click();')
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    items  = soup.select('.grid-item-content')
    titles  = [item.find("p", {"class" : lambda L: L and L.startswith('product-display-name')}).text.strip() for item in items]
    links = [item.find('a')['href'] for item in items]
    results = list(zip(titles, links))
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    for result in results:
        res = s.get(result[1])
        soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
        print(result[1])
        details = [item for item in soup.select('.description-preview fs16-sm css-1pbvugb')]
        print(details)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like JS render to page.You can take the driver.page_source again inside iteration.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from random import randint
from time import sleep
#'/Users/Selenium/bin/chromedriver'
final = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Selenium/bin/chromedriver')
    ###########THIS IS THE URL
    driver.get('https://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-tennis-shoes/7puZ8r0Zoi3')
    products = [element for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='grid-item fullSize']")))]
    driver.execute_script('el = document.elementFromPoint(47, 457); el.click();')
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    items  = soup.select('.grid-item-content')
    titles  = [item.find("p", {"class" : lambda L: L and L.startswith('product-display-name')}).text.strip() for item in items]
    links = [item.find('a')['href'] for item in items]
    results = list(zip(titles, links))
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    for result in results:
        driver.get(result[1])
        soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        print(result[1])
        details = [item.text for item in soup.select('.description-preview.fs16-sm.css-1pbvugb')]
        print(details)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
https://www.nike.com/t/nikecourt-air-zoom-vapor-x-mens-hard-court-tennis-shoe-6J0fk8/AA8030-103
['With Nike Zoom Air and a Dynamic Fit system, the NikeCourt Air Zoom Vapor X provides ultimate control on hard courts.Shown: White/BlackStyle: AA8030-103']
https://www.nike.com/t/nikecourt-zoom-cage-3-mens-hard-court-tennis-shoe-mbXWvX
['The NikeCourt Zoom Cage 3 is made for the player seeking strength and speed on the hard court. The shoe’s unique cage design provides maximum durability and cushioning, and is also lighter than ever.Shown: Black/WhiteStyle: 918193-006']
https://www.nike.com/t/nikecourt-air-zoom-zero-mens-tennis-shoe-nHMRHN
['Featuring the first full-length Zoom Air unit in NikeCourt history, the NikeCourt Air Zoom Zero delivers exceptional responsiveness and great court feel. Its snug-fitting upper and webbed lacing system offer second-skin-like comfort and lockdown.Shown: Black/Black/WhiteStyle: AA8018-003']
https://www.nike.com/t/nikecourt-air-max-wildcard-mens-tennis-shoe-p9NhX7
['The NikeCourt Air Max Wildcard delivers the comfort you need to hit hard and move fast on the court. A Max Air unit under your heel cushions every step, while an innovative Lunarlon midsole provides a springy underfoot sensation and extra stability.Shown: Black/Phantom/Bright Crimson/PhantomStyle: AO7351-006']
https://www.nike.com/t/nikecourt-zoom-cage-3-mens-hard-court-tennis-shoe-l3qpKZ/918193-005
['The NikeCourt Zoom Cage 3 is made for the player seeking strength and speed on the hard court. The shoe’s unique cage design provides maximum durability and cushioning, and is also lighter than ever.Shown: Platinum Tint/Laser Fuchsia/Thunder GreyStyle: 918193-005']
https://www.nike.com/t/nikecourt-air-zoom-resistance-mens-hard-court-tennis-shoe-qmZW1o/918194-003
['The\xa0NikeCourt Air Zoom Resistance delivers lightweight durability on the hard court with a performance leather upper.Shown: Black/Bright Crimson/WhiteStyle: 918194-003']
https://www.nike.com/t/nikecourt-air-zoom-prestige-mens-hard-court-tennis-shoe-vY8981
['The NikeCourt Air Zoom Prestige combines the responsiveness of Zoom Air technology with the lockdown of Dynamic Fit for glove-like comfort and support on hard courts.Shown: Vast Grey/Indigo Force/Indigo ForceStyle: AA8020-054']
https://www.nike.com/t/nikecourt-lite-mens-hard-court-tennis-shoe-7qqvCd
['The NikeCourt Lite is built for total comfort with a premium upper and a durable outsole designed for hard\xa0courts.Shown: White/Medium Grey/BlackStyle: 845021-100']
https://www.nike.com/t/nikecourt-lite-mens-hard-court-tennis-shoe-VrTWWAE1/845021-054
['The NikeCourt Lite is built for total comfort with a premium upper and a durable outsole designed for hard\xa0courts.Shown: Vast Grey/Indigo ForceStyle: 845021-054']
```

Comment: unfortunately Im not getting the text I want from this row -> `details = [item for item in soup.select('.description-preview.fs16-sm.css-1pbvugb')]`

Comment: can tell here which text value you are after?

Comment: @Hachi : check my updated answer.Is that you are after.

Comment: thank you very much for providing one solution! Although I didnt want to visit each href links this still satisfies the output I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to see if I can go straight to the API and grab that, but couldn't seem to find it. However it is available in the `<script>` tags in the json format. Just a matter of finding it, then iterating through to get what you want. There's also price, customer reviews, and all sorts of data within there:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import json

final = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update({'Accept-Language': 'en-US'})
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
    ###########THIS IS THE URL 
    driver.get('https://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-tennis-shoes/7puZ8r0Zoi3')
    products = [element for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='grid-item fullSize']")))]
    driver.execute_script('el = document.elementFromPoint(47, 457); el.click();')
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    items  = soup.select('.grid-item-content')
    titles  = [item.find("p", {"class" : lambda L: L and L.startswith('product-display-name')}).text.strip() for item in items]
    links = [item.find('a')['href'] for item in items]
    results = list(zip(titles, links))
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    for result in results:

        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US'}

        res = s.get(result[1], headers=headers )
        soup = bs(res.text, 'lxml')
        print(result[1])

        scripts = soup.find_all('script')
        for script in scripts:
            if 'window.INITIAL_REDUX_STATE=' in script.text:
                jsonStr = script.text.split('window.INITIAL_REDUX_STATE=')[1]
                jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit(';',1)[0]
                jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)

                for k, v in jsonData['Threads']['products'].items():
                    details = bs(v['description'], 'lxml').text
        print(details,'\n')
driver.quit()
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.nike.com/t/nikecourt-air-zoom-vapor-x-mens-hard-court-tennis-shoe-6J0fk8/AA8030-103
ULTRALIGHT SPEED.With Nike Zoom Air and a Dynamic Fit system, the NikeCourt Air Zoom Vapor X provides ultimate control on hard courts.Secure FitThe Dynamic Fit system wraps your foot from the bottom of the arch up to the laces for a glove-like fit.Responsive CushioningA Zoom Air unit in the heel offers low-profile, resilient cushioning from swing to swing.Quick StabilityThe full-length TPU foot frame wraps up the outside of your foot for added stability on every turn and swing.More BenefitsPadded collar provides additional comfort.Built up rubber on the toe increases durability and protection from drag.Non-marking rubber outsole for durable traction on hard courts.Shown: Black/Bright Crimson/WhiteStyle: AA8030-016 

https://www.nike.com/t/nikecourt-zoom-cage-3-mens-hard-court-tennis-shoe-mbXWvX
STRENGTH AND SPEED.The NikeCourt Zoom Cage 3 is made for the player seeking strength and speed on the hard court. The shoe’s unique cage design provides maximum durability and cushioning, and is also lighter than ever.Maximum DurabilityMade with a lightweight CPU cage built up in the high wear zone areas specific to tennis. “Zoned” cage adds stability without adding weight.Exceptional TractionThe modified herringbone outsole delivers excellent traction and durability. Ideal for hard court surfaces.
Complete ComfortNike Zoom Air unit in the heel delivers responsive, lightweight cushioning.More BenefitsExternal heel clip is efficiently shaped to secure the heel.Flexible support in the midfoot provides lightweight stability.Full bootie construction wraps your foot for a snug fit.Kurim material on upper allows for elasticity and flexibility.Shown: White/Light Carbon/Light Blue Fury/ObsidianStyle: 918193-104 

https://www.nike.com/t/nikecourt-air-zoom-zero-mens-tennis-shoe-nHMRHN
COURT FEEL, OPTIMIZED.Featuring the first full-length Zoom Air unit in NikeCourt history, the NikeCourt Air Zoom Zero delivers exceptional responsiveness and great court feel. Its snug-fitting upper and webbed lacing system offer second-skin-like comfort and lockdown.BenefitsFull-length Zoom Air unit is curved to deliver responsive cushioning.Integrated crash pad helps promote a smooth heel-to-toe transition.1/2 sleeve provides a snug, sock-like fit.Gilly straps on the medial and lateral side integrate with the laces for a customizable fit.Midsole foam on top of the front Zoom Air unit brings the unit closer to the ground.Midsole foam underneath the back of the Zoom Air unit brings the unit closer to your heel.Outsole is cored out in the middle to reduce weight and show off the Zoom Air unit.Outsole material wraps over the toe on the medial side for added durability while sliding.Shown: Vast Grey/Indigo ForceStyle: AA8018-044 
...
```

Comment: first thank you so much for helping, your code is working, however something weird is happening. I am working in Japan right now and all the product descriptions are some how shown in Japanese. Could you guide me please on where I can find this <script> tag. How can I spot the json format?

Comment: I made a slight change. Try it and see if that works. I'll explain the rest after we figure out this language thing.

Comment: nope, its still the same. I also get this error at the end:
`
---> 44                 for k, v in jsonData['Threads']['products'].items():
     45                     details = bs(v['description'], 'lxml').text
     46         print(details,'\n')

KeyError: 'products'`

Comment: ok. Odd I'm not getting that error and it runs all the way through. What versions of the packages are you using?. As far as the language, you're going to have to figure out how to change the browser settings/location. I'm not quite sure how that's done as I never had to do that.

Comment: allow me to figure this language issue first because it seems the main issue. I compared the number of items in the japanese website and there was an item missing, which means that your code is working but cannot find information in the japanese content. Will post if I can figure this out... Thank you chitown88

Comment: ok. and yes, please post back when you find the solution to the language. I'm curious how that would be done.